# How can I make a proccess in an OnLButtonDown() event happen again and again untill I live the button?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

What happen until now is this:

Any line happens once, and if I use a`while(1)` or `while (nFlags == MK_LBUTTON)` its working as it should but I get a crash.

The other problem, or maybe the same one is the delay if I will be able to do it, maybe using `while()` with `Timer()`?

I was thinking about `Timer()` to recall the function with delay but I can't call `OnLButtonDown()` because asI understand it only a message can call it with the arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `OnLButtonDown()` call `SetTimer()` to start a timer running, eg. every 100ms.  Then add `OnLButtonUp()` and call `KillTimer()` to stop the timer running.  Then, do your code in the `OnTimer()` function (add `WM_TIMER` to the message map) and it will run while the mouse is held down.

Note if the user clicks and drags the mouse outside your window, you get `OnLButtonDown()` called but not `OnLButtonUp()` which can leave the program thinking the mouse button is stuck down.  The functions to deal with this are: call `SetCapture()` at the same time as `SetTimer()` and `ReleaseCapture()` at the same time as `KillTimer()` to keep receiving mouse messages no matter where the mouse is.  I'd advise looking up all the functions I've mentioned in this answer on MSDN and reading up on them for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using while loops, remember the old mousestate.

```
if (oldFlags == MK_LBUTTON && nFlags == MK_LBUTTON)
```

That way you know that the user is holding the button and didn't just recently click it.

But you can send WM messages to fool your application that the button has been pressed to if you want.
I can't really guide you in any particular direction because im not really sure what you want to accomplish ;P This is the best answer I can give you from the little I understood of your question.

Comment: It didn't work, not for me any way......
I am trying to create an airbrush effect, that is why i need to call the lbnckicked function again and again untill i stop pushing the button...